# How to style nested controls in UWP with a single style?

Tags: xaml, uwp, styles

In a UWP project I got a TextBlock inside a Border, inside a Button. Like this:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyBtnStyle}">
   <Border>
     <TextBlock/>
   </Border>
</Button>
```

I want to set a style that customize all the controls at once. Something like this:

```
<Style x:Name="MyBtnStyle" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
   <Style TargetType="Border>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
       <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
       <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
       </Style>
   </Style>  
</Style>
```

Is there a way to do that? If no, what is the best aproach to this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you could not do that. You could create a style for the Button and change the template property of it. Then you could customize the border and textblock as you want to replace the default ContentPresenter in the default button style.

Another way is just to create three sperate styles for each part and use them separately.